# showing alert box in php

Tags: php, html

in the below code , the alert box is appearing in another window when values are not entered in the fields. but i want the alert box to appear in the same window of html page( detail.htm).how can i do this?

**detail.htm:**

```
<body>    
    <h1> Product: </h1>
    <form  action="product.php"  method="post"  >
        <input type="text" name= "product_id" size="15" />
        <input type="text" name= "price" size="10"/>
        <input type = "submit"  value = "enter" /> 
    </form>        
</body>
```

**product.php:**

```
if (empty($_POST["product_id"]) || empty($_POST["price"])) {
    echo "<script>alert('You must enter both values.')</script>";
} else {
    include 'product.htm';
}
```

Comment: You'd need to use JavaScript in the `detail.htm` page.

Comment: David Thomas but i already used javascript in php file

Comment: "Always used" is hardly an argument, sounds more like an excuse to me.

Comment: @kalvin: But the question is about how you _don't want the popup to come out of the PHP file_, but from the original page. Make up your mind!

Comment: @hakre: Where did you see that?

Comment: @tomalak: By perception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use client side validation:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function validate() {
        if (document.forms[0].product_id.value == "") {
            window.alert("You must enter both values");
            return false;
        }
        if (document.forms[0].price.value == "") {
            window.alert("You must enter both values");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And then call the `validate()` function on `onsubmit` event of `FORM` like

```
<form action="product.php"  method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement a client-side check in Javascript for that to happen.

Comment: Yes, but you missed the point. He's already doing that, just in the wrong place.

Comment: Uhm, mentioned "client-side", didn't I?

Comment: Yes, and he's already doing it on the client-side (how else could an alert box appear?!). Just after submission rather than before.

Comment: Oh, well.. I suppose he's doing the alert on the client-side but the _check_ on the server-side. Fine :P

Answer (score 0):

Give your form an ID, use JavaScript (or with a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)) and do something like the following:

```
$('#id-of-the-form').submit(function(e) {
    var self = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    var found_empty = false;
    $('#id-of-the-form').find(':input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            found_empty = true;
        }
    });
    if (found_empty) {
        alert('Please enter all values!');
    }
    else {
        $(this).submit();
    }
});
```

Please note that i am using jQuery in this example!

As a reference, i'm using jQuery to observe the submission of the form, get all fields of the form and check if the fields aren't empty. If they're empty, it alerts, if not - it submits.

Comment: SiteSafeNL  but i havnt used jQuery before. Can you please just use javascript

Comment: Kalvin, why not use jQuery? It's a small library wich contains loads of functions you can use later on :) It's easier with jQuer then with native JavaScript..